# pandas pivot_table giving IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe of the following format:

```
reviewerID   asin     overall 
abc          def       2.0
mno          pqr       3.0
```

I am trying to pivot it as follows:

```
p = pd.DataFrame.pivot_table(ratings_df, index='reviewerID', columns='asin', values='overall').fillna(0)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> IndexError: index 1349974861 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1349882510

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are most likely [running out of memory](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582).